# How to locate the file backing a Custom Keychain

Tags: keychain

I have a Custom Keychain configured in the Keychain Access app:

[image: Screenshot of Keychain Access with home keychain highlighted]

I'd like to find where that file is on disk. I've poked around the app but I can't find a way to resolve that keychain to its location on disk. It's definitely not found in the default location ~/Library/Keychains.

I searched around online, including [this Apple article](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/keychain-access/kyca1121/mac), but I haven't yet found a way to resolve that keychain to its location.

To be sure, that file exists in multiple locations on my system, so I need to determine precisely which one the keychain is relying on.

Answer (score 2):

While I was typing up the question, it occurred to me that the `security` CLI application might help, and indeed it does:

```
 ~ @ security help | grep keychains
    list-keychains                       Display or manipulate the keychain search list.
    create-keychain                      Create keychains and add them to the search list.
    delete-keychain                      Delete keychains and remove them from the search list.
    dump-keychain                        Dump the contents of one or more keychains.
```

And simply running the `list-keychains` command gave me exactly what I needed:

```
 ~ @ security list-keychains
    "/Users/jaraco/.local/Keychains/home.keychain-db"
    "/Users/jaraco/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db"
    "/Library/Keychains/System.keychain"
```